# Why does instantiating a Gson object throw java.lang.VerifyError?

Tags: java, android, gson

I have inherited a project and have been migrating it from the original Eclipse workspace to Android Studio.

For some reason when the following code causes an exception:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/gson/Gson
    at com.example.example.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:59)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This occurs on two 4.4.2 devices but not on 5.1.1.

I have tried:

- Using an older version of the GSON library
- Repackaging the library (http://cases.azoft.com/fix-verifyerror-android-apps-gson-library/)

Comment: use this compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'

Comment: No effect I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my issue was caused by `multiDexEnabled true`. I turned this off and resolved my 65k issue by following this: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/google-play-services-and-dex-method.html

No issues since.